# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, twitter

I am working on a code which gets realtime tweets from twitter based on search term and save it to Mysql database. But when I run the code while inserting into database it raises an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I cannot understand what the problem is here is the code to insert into database

```
tweet = json.loads(data);
    #print json.dumps(tweet, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    #print tweet['text']
    tweetid = tweet['id_str']
    userid = tweet['user']['id_str']
    text = tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO twitterfeeeds(tweet_id, user_id,body,status) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,'0')"""%(tweetid,userid,text))
    db.commit()
```

Here body is text in tweet and status is whether it is processed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't encode your tweet to UTF-8, and don't use string formatting to create the query.

Use SQL parameters instead:

```
tweetid = tweet['id_str']
userid = tweet['user']['id_str']
text = tweet['text']
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO twitterfeeeds(tweet_id, user_id,body,status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, '0')""",
    (tweetid, userid, text))
```

Yes, there is a difference between the above code and yours; the `tweetid`, `userid` and `text` values are all passed in as one separate argument (a tuple) to the `cursor.execute()` method.

It is the responsibility of the cursor to handle proper escaping of your data to insert into the database. This way you avoid SQL injection attacks (a tweet with `;DROP TABLE twitterfeeeds` would destroy your database right now), and enable query plan optimisations.

This all does require you configure your database connection to support Unicode data; set the character set to UTF-8 on the connection:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user='root', password='', 
                       db='', charset='utf8')
```

or better still, configure the database to use the UTF8MB4 character set (the UTF-8 version MySQL uses can not handle emoji or other codepoints beyond U+FFFF):

```
# Note, no characterset specified
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user='root', password='', db='')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4')
```

Comment: when tweet is not encoded it raises another error
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 234: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: @Harwee: not when passed in as a query parameter.

Comment: @Harwee: you do need to configure your database to accept UTF-8 Unicode text, currently your database can only handle Latin-1.

Answer (score 1):

use can use MySQLdb.escape_string for escaping unicode chars.

```
>> MySQLdb.escape_string("'")
"\\'"
```

additionally i think you have to open your 'mysql.connector' with 'use_unicode':True config:

```
config = {
'user': ...,
'password': ...,
'host': '127.0.0.1',
'use_unicode':True,
'charset':'utf8',
}
db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```